# Shiny app keeps aborting, presumably because of plot function from textplot package

Tags: r, shiny, rendering, topic-modeling, abort

Dear people of stackoverflow,
This post is about a shiny app that performs topic modeling on text data. It runs the model, visualizes the topics and zooms in within each topic.
The problem is that the app aborts the R session after a few minutes. I tried to use the line of code update.packages(ask = FALSE, checkBuilt = TRUE), but the shiny app still aborts the session after updating the packages. I worked with R version 3.6.3, but I also tried to make it work with R version 4.0 and 4.0.2.
I have provided the output and session info for version 3.6.3 in this post. I am working inside a test environment. I also copy pasted my code below. You may ignore the comments in Dutch within the code, I have translated the comments to English whenever necessary. Normally it takes a couple of minutes before the session aborts, but it is never at the same line of code or same click.
Dummy data is available at the beginning of the code. When I run the app with the dummy data instead of my real data, the session is not aborted. I also tried with more dummy data, but I get the same result. When I remove the part where the plot function from the textplot library is used, the session is also not aborting. The plot function takes a lot of time and is most likely causing the problem. Do you know how I can solve this problem while still displaying a visualization of the topics?

```
Information version 3.6.3: 
> devtools::session_info()
- Session info ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 setting  value                       
 version  R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29)
 os       Windows 10 x64              
 system   x86_64, mingw32             
 ui       RStudio                     
 language (EN)                        
 collate  Dutch_Netherlands.1252      
 ctype    Dutch_Netherlands.1252      
 tz       Europe/Berlin               
 date     2020-07-13                  

- Packages ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 package        * version  date       lib source        
 assertthat       0.2.1    2019-03-21 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 backports        1.1.8    2020-06-17 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 blob             1.2.1    2020-01-20 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 broom            0.7.0    2020-07-09 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 BTM            * 0.3.1    2020-05-02 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 Cairo          * 1.5-12.2 2020-07-07 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 callr            3.4.3    2020-03-28 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 cellranger       1.1.0    2016-07-27 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 cli              2.0.2    2020-02-28 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 colorspace       1.4-1    2019-03-18 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 concaveman     * 1.1.0    2020-05-11 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 crayon           1.3.4    2017-09-16 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 data.table     * 1.12.8   2019-12-09 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 DBI              1.1.0    2019-12-15 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 dbplyr           1.4.4    2020-05-27 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 desc             1.2.0    2018-05-01 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 devtools         2.3.0    2020-04-10 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 digest           0.6.25   2020-02-23 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 dplyr          * 1.0.0    2020-05-29 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 ellipsis         0.3.1    2020-05-15 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 fansi            0.4.1    2020-01-08 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 farver           2.0.3    2020-01-16 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 fastmap          1.0.1    2019-10-08 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 forcats        * 0.5.0    2020-03-01 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 fs               1.4.2    2020-06-30 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 generics         0.0.2    2018-11-29 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 ggforce          0.3.2    2020-06-23 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 ggplot2        * 3.3.2    2020-06-19 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 ggraph         * 2.0.3    2020-05-20 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 ggrepel          0.8.2    2020-03-08 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 glue             1.4.1    2020-05-13 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 graphlayouts     0.7.0    2020-04-25 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 gridExtra        2.3      2017-09-09 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 gtable           0.3.0    2019-03-25 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 haven            2.3.1    2020-06-01 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 hms              0.5.3    2020-01-08 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 htmltools        0.5.0    2020-06-16 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 httpuv           1.5.4    2020-06-06 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 httr             1.4.1    2019-08-05 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 igraph           1.2.5    2020-03-19 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 jsonlite         1.7.0    2020-06-25 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 later            1.1.0.1  2020-06-05 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 lattice          0.20-41  2020-04-02 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 lifecycle        0.2.0    2020-03-06 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 lubridate        1.7.9    2020-06-08 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 magrittr         1.5      2014-11-22 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 MASS             7.3-51.6 2020-04-26 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 Matrix           1.2-18   2019-11-27 [2] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 memoise          1.1.0    2017-04-21 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 mime             0.9      2020-02-04 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.2)
 modelr           0.1.8    2020-05-19 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 munsell          0.5.0    2018-06-12 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 pillar           1.4.6    2020-07-10 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 pkgbuild         1.0.8    2020-05-07 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 pkgconfig        2.0.3    2019-09-22 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 pkgload          1.1.0    2020-05-29 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 polyclip         1.10-0   2019-03-14 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 prettyunits      1.1.1    2020-01-24 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 processx         3.4.3    2020-07-05 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 promises         1.1.1    2020-06-09 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 ps               1.3.3    2020-05-08 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 purrr          * 0.3.4    2020-04-17 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 R6               2.4.1    2019-11-12 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 Rcpp             1.0.5    2020-07-06 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 readr          * 1.3.1    2018-12-21 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 readxl           1.3.1    2019-03-13 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 remotes          2.1.1    2020-02-15 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 reprex           0.3.0    2019-05-16 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 rlang            0.4.7    2020-07-09 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 rprojroot        1.3-2    2018-01-03 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 rstudioapi       0.11     2020-02-07 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 rvest            0.3.5    2019-11-08 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 scales           1.1.1    2020-05-11 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 sessioninfo      1.1.1    2018-11-05 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 shiny          * 1.5.0    2020-06-23 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 shinydashboard * 0.7.1    2018-10-17 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 shinyWidgets   * 0.5.3    2020-06-01 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 stopwords      * 2.0      2020-04-14 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 stringi          1.4.6    2020-02-17 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.2)
 stringr        * 1.4.0    2019-02-10 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 testthat         2.3.2    2020-03-02 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 textplot       * 0.1.3    2020-06-18 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 tibble         * 3.0.3    2020-07-10 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 tidygraph        1.2.0    2020-05-12 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 tidyr          * 1.1.0    2020-05-20 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 tidyselect       1.1.0    2020-05-11 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 tidyverse      * 1.3.0    2019-11-21 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 tweenr           1.0.1    2018-12-14 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 udpipe         * 0.8.3    2019-07-05 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 usethis          1.6.1    2020-04-29 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 vctrs            0.3.1    2020-06-05 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 viridis          0.5.1    2018-03-29 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 viridisLite      0.3.0    2018-02-01 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 withr            2.2.0    2020-04-20 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 xml2             1.3.2    2020-04-23 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 xtable           1.8-4    2019-04-21 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)

[1] H:/Mijn documenten/R/win-library/3.6
[2] C:/Program Files/R/R-3.6.3/library
```

Dummy data code:

```
Library(stringi) 
Library(data.table)
Library(udpipe)
Library(BTM)
dataset <- data.frame(doc_id = rep(seq(1,500,1),20), lemma = stri_rand_strings(10000, 10, '[A-Z]'), jaar_ontvangst = 2020, maand_ontvangst = 1, mel_melding_wetCombinatie = as.character(rep(seq(1,25,1),400)), domein_AMF = rep(c("J", "N"),5000), domein_ARBO = rep(c("N", "J"),5000), kvk_sbiSectie = as.character(rep(seq(1,25,1),400)), kvk_sbiSectie = as.character(rep(seq(1,25,1),400)), mel_fimo_beslissing = as.character(rep(seq(1,25,1),400)), mel_inhoud_onderwerp = as.character(rep(seq(1,25,1),400)), provincie = as.character(rep(seq(1,25,1),400)))
mel_inhoud_origineel <- dataset %>% group_by(doc_id) %>% mutate(mel_inhoud_orgineel_30k = paste0(lemma, collapse = " ")) %>% select(mel_inhoud_orgineel_30k) %>% distinct()
df <- data.frame(doc_id = as.character(seq(1,500,1)), mel_inhoud_orgineel_30k = mel_inhoud_origineel$mel_inhoud_orgineel_30k, jaar_ontvangst = 2020, maand_ontvangst = 1, mel_melding_wetCombinatie = as.character(rep(seq(1,25,1),20)), domein_AMF = rep(c("J", "N"),250), domein_ARBO = rep(c("N", "J"),250), kvk_sbiSectie = as.character(rep(seq(1,25,1),20)), kvk_sbiSectie = as.character(rep(seq(1,25,1),20)), mel_fimo_beslissing = as.character(rep(seq(1,25,1),20)), mel_inhoud_onderwerp = as.character(rep(seq(1,25,1),20)), provincie = as.character(rep(seq(1,25,1),20)))

tweekolom <- dataset %>%
  select(doc_id, lemma)

#biterms aanmaken
window <- 10
biterms <- as.data.table(tweekolom)
biterms <-  biterms[, cooccurrence(x = lemma,
                                  skipgram = window),
                   by = list(doc_id)]
```

App code :

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shinydashboard)
library(data.table)
library(stopwords)
library(BTM)
library(textplot)
library(ggraph)
library(tidyverse)
library(udpipe)
library(concaveman)
library(Cairo)
options(shiny.usecairo=T)

#labels sbi sector
sbi_opties <- levels(dataset$kvk_sbiSectie)

# Define UI ----
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Biterm topic modeling bij Meldingsteksten"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("Topicmodeling", tabName = "topicmodeling"),
      menuItem("Inzoomen", tabName = "zoomen")
      )
    ),  
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem(tabName = "topicmodeling", 
    # Output: wordcloud ----
    fluidRow(column(10,
                    box(title = "Word cloud", width = 12,
                        plotOutput(outputId = "wordcloud"))),
             column(2, 
                    fluidRow(box(title = "Totaal aantal meldingen", width = 12, 
                                 div(tableOutput('totaalmeldingen'),
                                     style = "font-size:150%"))), 
                    fluidRow(box(title = "Aantal meldingen in geselecteerde onderwerp", width = 12, 
                                 div(tableOutput('aantalmeldingeninonderwerp'),
                                     style = "font-size:150%"))))),
     #All the filters for plotting
    fluidRow(
      box(title = "Plotten", width = 6, solidHeader = TRUE,
          # Input: Slider for the amount of words to show per topic
          sliderInput(inputId = "top_n",
                      label = "Limiet aantal woorden per topic:",
                      min = 1,
                      max = 30,
                      value = 7),
          #input voor het aantal topics om te plotten
          uiOutput('topic_select1')),
      #This area lets the user choose settings for running the model
      box(title = "Model runnen", width = 6, solidHeader = TRUE,
          #input for the amount of months
          pickerInput(
            inputId = "ARBO_AMF",
            label = "Selecteer ARBO of AMF:",
            choices = c("ARBO", "AMF"),
            options = list(
              `actions-box` = TRUE,
              size = 10,
              `selected-text-format` = "count > 3"
            ),
            multiple = TRUE
          ),
          pickerInput(
            inputId = "maand_select",
            label = "Selecteer maanden:",
            choices = seq(1, 12, 1),
            options = list(
              `actions-box` = TRUE,
              size = 10,
              `selected-text-format` = "count > 3"
            ),
            multiple = TRUE
          ),
          #input for the amount of years
          pickerInput(
            inputId = "jaar_select",
            label = "Selecteer jaren:",
            choices = c(2019, 2020),
            options = list(
              `actions-box` = TRUE,
              size = 10,
              `selected-text-format` = "count > 3"
            ),
            multiple = TRUE
          ),
          # select amount of clusters for the model
          # The minimum and maximum values do not work
          numericInput(inputId = "aantal_clusters", 
                       label = "Selecteer maximaal aantal clusters om model op te runnen", 
                       value = 10, 
                       min = 3, 
                       max = 200),
          #input for the sectors
          pickerInput(
            inputId = "sector_select",
            label = "Selecteer sectoren vooraf:",
            choices = sbi_opties,
            selected = sbi_opties,
            options = list(
              `actions-box` = TRUE,
              size = 10,
              `selected-text-format` = "count > 3"
            ),
            multiple = TRUE
          ),
          actionButton("runBTM", "Klik hier om de topic modeling te runnen met de gekozen instellingen"))
    )),
  tabItem(tabName = "zoomen", fluidRow(column(3,box(width = 12, 
                                                    uiOutput('onderwerpen1'))),
    column(3, box(title = "Geselecteerde onderwerpen", 
                  width = 12, 
                  uiOutput('sectoren1'),
                  uiOutput('beslissing1'),
                  uiOutput('onderwerpen12')
                  #tableOutput('geselecteerdeonderwerp')
                  )), 
    column(3, box(title = "Top woorden in onderwerp", 
                  width = 12,
                      tableOutput('topwoorden')))),
    tabsetPanel(tabPanel("Meldingen", 
                         fluidPage(fluidRow(column(3, box(width = 12, 
                                                       plotOutput('verdelingwetten'))),
                                            column(3, box(width = 12,
                                                          plotOutput('beslissing'))),
                                            column(6,box(width = 12, 
                                                         plotOutput('verdeling_sbi')))),
                                   fluidRow(box(width = 12, 
                                                plotOutput("onderwerpverdeling"))),
                                   fluidRow(column(4,
                                                   box(width = 12, 
                                                       plotOutput("provincieverdeling")),
                                                   ),
                                            column(8,box(width = 12, tableOutput('meldingen')))
                                            )
                                   )
                         )
                )
    )
  )))

# Define server  ----
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  #Selecting which subjects to display in first tab. I put the pickerinput inside the server, because the model$K is interactive.
  output$topic_select1 = renderUI({
    model <- model()
    pickerInput(
      inputId = "topic_select",
      label = "Selecteer topics:",
      choices = 1:model$K,
      selected = 1:model$K,
      options = list(
        `actions-box` = TRUE,
        size = 10,
        `selected-text-format` = "count > 3"
      ),
      multiple = TRUE
    )
  })
  
  # Selecting which subjects to display in second tab. I put the pickerinput inside the server, because the model$K is interactive.
  output$onderwerpen1 <- renderUI({
    model <- model()
    pickerInput(
    inputId = 'onderwerpen', 
    label = 'Selecteer het onderwerp waarvoor je de meldingen wilt zien', 
    choices = 1:model$K, 
    selected = input$topic_select,
    options = list(
      `actions-box` = TRUE,
      size = 10,
      `selected-text-format` = "count > 3"
    ),
    multiple = TRUE)
  })
  
  # Selecting which sectors to display in first tab. I put the pickerinput inside the server, because the input$sector_select is interactive.
  output$sectoren1 <- renderUI({
    pickerInput(inputId = "sector_select_achteraf",
              label = "Selecteer sectoren binnen een onderwerp:",
              choices = input$sector_select,
              selected = input$sector_select,
              options = list(
                `actions-box` = TRUE,
                size = 10,
                `selected-text-format` = "count > 3"
              ),
              multiple = TRUE
  )
  })
  
  #Selecting decisions
  output$beslissing1 <- renderUI({
    pickerInput(
      inputId = "beslissingachteraf",
      label = "Selecteer beslissing FIMO:",
      choices = as.vector(unique(dataset$mel_fimo_beslissing)),
      selected = as.vector(unique(dataset$mel_fimo_beslissing)),
      options = list(
        `actions-box` = TRUE,
        size = 10,
        `selected-text-format` = "count > 3"
      ),
      multiple = TRUE
    )
  })
  
  #Selecting subjects
  output$onderwerpen12 <- renderUI({
    pickerInput(
      inputId = "onderwerpenachteraf",
      label = "Selecteer onderwerp:",
      choices = levels(dataset$mel_inhoud_onderwerp),
      options = list(
        `actions-box` = TRUE,
        size = 10,
        `selected-text-format` = "count > 3"
      ),
      multiple = TRUE
    )
  })
  
  #Selecting the chosen texts 
  doc_select <- reactive({
    docs <- dataset$doc_id
    #Check whether a decision was made between two options
    if (!is.null(input$ARBO_AMF)){
      print(input$ARBO_AMF)
      #Als AMF en ARBO beide zijn geselecteerd worden alle meldingen gebruikt
      if ("AMF" %in% input$ARBO_AMF & "ARBO" %in% input$ARBO_AMF){
        docs <- dataset %>% 
          select(doc_id)
      }
      #If just one item is selected. 
      else if ("ARBO" %in% input$ARBO_AMF){
        dataset <- dataset %>%
        filter(domein_ARBO == "J") 
        docs <- dataset %>% 
        select(doc_id)
      }
      #If the other item is selected
      else if ("AMF" %in% input$ARBO_AMF){
        dataset <- dataset %>%
          filter(domein_AMF == "J") 
        docs <- dataset %>% 
          select(doc_id)
      }

    }
    #Select texts from chosen months
    if (!is.null(input$maand_select)){
      dataset <- dataset %>%
        filter(maand_ontvangst %in% input$maand_select) 
      docs <- dataset %>% 
        select(doc_id)
    }
    #Select texts from chosen sector
    if (!is.null(input$sector_select)){
      dataset <- dataset %>%
        filter(kvk_sbiSectie %in% input$sector_select) 
      docs <- dataset %>% 
        select(doc_id)
    }
    #Select texts that were from the chosen year
    if (!is.null(input$jaar_select)){
      dataset <- dataset %>%
        filter(jaar_ontvangst %in% input$jaar_select) 
      docs <- dataset %>% 
        select(doc_id)
    }
    as.vector(as.matrix(docs))
  })
  
  #All id’s were selected
  #Now the texts are selected that have the same id

  data_select <- reactive({
    data <- tweekolom %>%
      filter(doc_id %in% doc_select())
    
      validate(
        need(nrow(data) > 0, "Er zijn geen meldingen beschikbaar in de geselecteerde periode")
      )
    data
    
  })
  
  #Select biterms that belong to those id’s
  biterm_select <- reactive({
    biterm <- biterms %>%
      filter(doc_id %in% doc_select())
    biterm
    
  })
  
  #make model
  #Click on actionbutton first
  model <- eventReactive(input$runBTM,{
      data <- data_select()
      bit <- biterm_select()
      k <- input$aantal_clusters
      model <- BTM(data = data, 
                                   biterms = bit, 
                                   k = k, 
                                   iter = 100, background = TRUE, trace = 20, detailed = FALSE)
      model
})
  
  #Make a visualisation of the model: This is a part where the session is often aborted. 

    output$wordcloud <- renderPlot({
    model <- model()
    #plotten model
    plot(model, 
         top_n = input$top_n, 
         labels = seq_len(model$K),
         which = c(input$topic_select))

  })

  #Elke melding moet in een onderwerp geplaatst worden. Elke melding krijgt nu per onderwerp een score:
  scores <- reactive({
    scores <- predict(model(), data_select())
    scores <- scores[names(table(doc_select())),]
    scores
  })
  
  #Selecteer per melding het onderwerp met de hoogste score. In dit onderwerp is die melding dan ingedeeld.
  labels <- reactive({
    labels <- apply(scores(),1,which.max)
    labels <- as.data.frame(labels)
    labels$doc_id <- rownames(labels)
    labels
  })
  
  #Als de gebruiker een ander onderwerp selecteert in het tweede tabblad, wordt ook de selectie van onderwerpen in het eerste tabblad verandert:
  observeEvent(input$onderwerpen,
               {
                 updateSelectInput(session = session,
                                   inputId = "topic_select",
                                   selected = input$onderwerpen)
               })
  #Ook andersom: Als de gebruiker een ander onderwerp selecteert in het eerste tabblad, wordt ook de selectie van onderwerpen in het tweede tabblad verandert:
  observeEvent(input$topic_select,
               {
                 updateSelectInput(session = session,
                                   inputId = "onderwerpen",
                                   selected = input$topic_select)
               })
  
  #Bereken het totaal aantal meldingen waarop de topic modeling is uitgevoerd zodat je dit kan weergeven op het eerste tabblad.
  output$totaalmeldingen <- renderTable({
    docs <- doc_select()
    length(unique(docs))}, colnames = FALSE)
  
  #Bereken het aantal meldingen die in het geselecteerde onderwerp zitten 
  output$aantalmeldingeninonderwerp <- renderTable({
    subject <- input$topic_select
    labels <- labels()
    docs2 <- labels$doc_id[labels$labels %in% subject]
    
    length(unique(docs2))},
    colnames = FALSE)
  
  #De geselecteerde sector op het tweede tabblad
  sectoren <- reactive({
    input$sector_select_achteraf
  })
  
  #Het geselecteerde onderwerp op het eerste tabblad
  subject <- reactive({
    input$topic_select
    })
  
  #De geselecteerde beslissing op het tweede tabblad
  beslissing <- reactive({
    input$beslissingachteraf
  })
  
  #Het geselecteerde vaste veld onderwerp op het tweede tabblad
  onderwerpachteraf <- reactive({
    input$onderwerpenachteraf
  })
  
  #De topwoorden per gemaakt onderwerp: 
  topicswords <- reactive({
    model <- model()
    topicswords <- terms(model, top_n = 5) %>%  
      bind_rows(.id = "topic")
    topicswords$token <- as.character(topicswords$token)
    topicswords
  })
  
  #Volgens mij gebruik ik deze code niet meer
  #Gebruikt om het geselecteerde onderwerp weer te geven in het tweede tabblad
  #output$geselecteerdeonderwerp <- renderTable({
  #  subject <- input$topic_select
   # t(as.data.frame(subject))}, colnames = FALSE)
  
  #Als de gebruiker wilt inzoomen op een ander onderwerp, moeten alleen die doc_ids geselecteerd worden.
  #De volgende code selecteert de doc_ids van de meldingen die op het tweede tabblad zijn geselecteerd.
  topicselecting <- reactive({
    docs <- doc_select()
    model <- model()
    data <- data_select()
    labels <- labels()
    topicswords <- topicswords()
    if (!is.null(subject())){
      docs2 <- labels$doc_id[labels$labels %in% subject()]
    }
    if(!is.null(sectoren())){
      docs2 <- df$doc_id[df$doc_id %in% docs2 & df$kvk_sbiSectie %in% sectoren()]
    }
    if (!is.null(beslissing())){
      docs2 <- df$doc_id[df$doc_id %in% docs2 & df$mel_fimo_beslissing %in% beslissing()]
    }
    if (!is.null(onderwerpachteraf())){
      docs2 <- df$doc_id[df$doc_id %in% docs2 & df$mel_inhoud_onderwerp %in% onderwerpachteraf()]
    }
    docs2
})
  
  #Maak een dataframe met alleen de complete meldingsteksten en de meldingsnummers van de geselecteerde doc_ids.
  meldingen_onderwerp <- reactive({
    docs2 <- topicselecting()
    meldingen_onderwerp <- as.data.frame(df[df$doc_id %in% docs2,]) %>% select(mel_inhoud_orgineel_30k, doc_id)
    colnames(meldingen_onderwerp) <- c("Meldingstekst", "Meldingsnummer")
    meldingen_onderwerp
  })
  
  #Selecteer de juiste rijen uit de dataset die zijn geselecteerd door topicselecting()
  data_onderwerp <- reactive({
    docs2 <- topicselecting()
    data_onderwerp <- dataset[dataset$doc_id %in% docs2,]    
    data_onderwerp
  })
  
  #Make an output table with the texts
    output$meldingen <- renderTable({
      meldingen_onderwerp()})
   
    #maak de outputtabel voor de topwoorden die voor de geselecteerde onderwerpen worden weergegeven
    output$topwoorden <- renderTable({
      topicswords <- topicswords()
      subject <- input$topic_select
      topicswords[topicswords$topic %in% subject,]
      })
    
    #make a barplot fort he distribution of texts across different laws
    output$verdelingwetten <- renderPlot({
      data_onderwerp <- data_onderwerp()
       ggplot(unique(data_onderwerp[,-2]), 
              aes(mel_melding_wetCombinatie, fill = mel_melding_wetCombinatie)) + 
         geom_bar() + 
         coord_flip() +
         theme(text = element_text(size = 15),legend.position = "none") +
         labs(x = "Wetcombinatie", y = "Aantal meldingen")
       }) 
     
    #Make a barplot for the distribution of texts across sectors
    output$verdeling_sbi <- renderPlot({
      data_onderwerp <- data_onderwerp()
      ggplot(unique(data_onderwerp[,-2]), 
              aes(kvk_sbiSectie, fill = kvk_sbiSectie)) + 
         geom_bar() + 
         coord_flip() +
         theme(text = element_text(size = 15),legend.position = "none") +
         labs(x = "SBI sectie", y = "Aantal meldingen")
     })
    #Make a barplot fort he distribution of texts across different decisions about the text
     output$beslissing <- renderPlot({
       data_onderwerp <- data_onderwerp()
       
       ggplot(unique(data_onderwerp[,-2]), 
              aes(mel_fimo_beslissing, fill = mel_fimo_beslissing)) + 
         geom_bar() + 
         coord_flip() +
         theme(text = element_text(size = 15),legend.position = "none") +
         labs(x = "Beslissing FIMO", y = "Aantal meldingen")
     })
     
     #Make a table with the structured field subjects
    output$onderwerpenachteraf <- renderTable({
      data_onderwerp <- data_onderwerp()
      unique(data_onderwerp$mel_inhoud_onderwerp)
    })
     
    #Make a barplot to see the distribution of texts across the structured subject field
    output$onderwerpverdeling <- renderPlot({
      data_onderwerp <- data_onderwerp()
      ggplot(unique(data_onderwerp[,-2]), 
             aes(mel_inhoud_onderwerp, fill = mel_inhoud_onderwerp)) + 
        geom_bar() + 
        coord_flip() +
        theme(text = element_text(size = 15), axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90), legend.position = "none") +
        labs(x = "Onderwerp", y = "Aantal meldingen")
    })
    
    #Make a barplot to see the distribution of texts across provinces
    output$provincieverdeling <- renderPlot({
      data_onderwerp <- data_onderwerp()
      
      ggplot(unique(data_onderwerp[,-2]), 
             aes(provincie, fill = provincie)) + 
        geom_bar() + 
        coord_flip() +
        theme(text = element_text(size = 15), axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90), legend.position = "none") +
        labs(x = "Provincie", y = "Aantal meldingen")
    })
 # })
  
}    
  
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Do you run this app in a server or locally?

Comment: could you try to reduce the problem to a minimal reproducible example : it will be easier for others to help you, and you might find the reason for the problem in this process.

Comment: I run it locally

Comment: Once I have time I will try to edit this post to a minimal reproducible example :)